# I tried using useHistory hook from react and it doesn;t work

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

```
App.js

import { Route, Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from './Pages/Login';
import Profile from './Pages/Profile';
import Routes from './Routes1/Route';



function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Routes />
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;

Route.js

import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import Login from '../Pages/Login';
import Profile from '../Pages/Profile';



const Routes = () => {
    const history = createBrowserHistory();
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default Routes;

Login.js

import React from 'react'
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'

function Login() {
        
        const history=useHistory();
        const handleHistory=() =>{
            history.push("/profile")
        }
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
            <input typ="text" placeholder="password" />
            <button onClick={handleHistory}> Submit </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login

Profile.js

import React from 'react'

function Profile() {
    return (
        <div>
            Congratulations! You have successfully logged in!
        </div>
    )
}

export default Profile

Package.json

{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.10",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.50",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.1.5",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "loadjs": "^4.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "pure-react-carousel": "^1.27.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-render-html": "^0.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "yup": "^0.28.3"
  },
  
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Error
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to see anything wrong in your code, however, you don't need the history in Routes component to that purpose, try to remove the following line:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory()
```

and history props in router.
Or instead of creating `handleSubmit` function try to pass `directly () => history.push()` at the `onClick`.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about `import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';`, but your code should work without it and with `BrowserRouter` as the router:

```
Route.js

import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from '../Pages/Login';
import Profile from '../Pages/Profile';



const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

Comment: This works fine.Thank you, but it doesnt fix my problem with the useHistory hook tho.

Comment: This issue seems to be related to your problem [https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7695](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7695) but I'm not sure how to fix this except by downgrading react to `16.xx`.